# Requisição angular não envia post

Tags: angularjs, json, http

boa noite!! seguinte...estou fazendo requisições assincronas com angularjs e ele funciona se usar o get e params, porém, se mudo para "post" e "data" ele para de enviar...vou postar aqui o controller e a página que recebe os dados:

```
app.controller('detalhe_carro', ProcessaAlteracao);

ProcessaAlteracao.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];

function ProcessaAlteracao($http, $scope) {
    $scope.titulo = 'detalhes do carro'
    $scope.tituloCarro = "";
    $scope.descricao = "";
    $scope.ano_carro = "";
    $scope.marca = "";
    $scope.mensagem = "";
    $scope.update = "";
    $scope.requisicao = function () {
          $http( {method: "POST",  url: $scope.update, data: { nome: $scope.tituloCarro }})
                .then(function (response)
                {
                    $scope.retorno = response.data
                    console.log(response);
                }
                , function (response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }
}
```

Agora, a página que recebe os dados:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8');
$x = array("info_recebida"=>$_REQUEST);
echo json_encode($x);
```

enfim , o que pode ter errado nesse código??? não sei como resolver isso, com post, não vai de forma alguma...

Comment: Está retornado algum erro ? 404, 500, etc.. ?

Comment: não,sem erros, eu imprimi a variável apache_request_headers() e não trouxe a variável que eu enviei...o que imprimiu foi isso:
Array ( [Host] => localhost [Connection] => keep-alive [Content-Length] => 0 [Accept] => application/json, text/plain, */* [Origin] => http://localhost [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36 [DNT] => 1 [Referer] => http://localhost/blog_da_corretora/site/ [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br [Accept-Language] => pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=vgjjj )

Comment: Bom `$scope.requisicao` é um função, você está chamando essa função ? Exemplo; `$scope.requisicao();`

Comment: estou chamando no html   <button ng-click="requisicao()">Alterar </button>